# useEffect race condition with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

Hello I have been struggling to set values when mounting a component. I am using useEffect Hook and useDispatch, useSelector for calling methods and also getting the state from the store. **The problem is that the state from the store is delayed 1 render and therefore I need to run two times the code inside useEffect in order to get the behavior I expect.** Which is -> when the component loads, do an API call and list some documents.

**Data declaration**

```
const data = useSelector(state => state.whole.manufactured);
```

**useEffect code**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (counter <= 1) {
      fetchData();
      setProducts(data);
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }

    console.log('data in store', data);
    console.log('useEffect');
  }, [clickedItem, data]);
```

**fetchData function**

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    await dispatch(get_manufacturing());
  };
```

**get_manufacturing**

```
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(Actions.uiStartLoading());

    fetch('http://myapi/api/product/get-products', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: Interceptor.getHeaders(),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        dispatch(Actions.uiStopLoading());

        if (result.status === true) {
          dispatch({type: TYPES.GET_MANUFACTURABLE, data: data});
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(Actions.uiStopLoading());
        console.log(error);
      });
```

When this code runs, the following happens.
[image: bug]

As you can see in the first render it seems it just completely ignorees the fetchData() and proceeds to the console.log, after the second render the values have been properly set. How can I resolve this issue is there something I'm not getting properly done?

Comment: Include counter variable in dependency list

Answer (score 1):

Replace `clickedItem` in the dependency list with `counter`.

Comment: The clickedItem is needed, also if the "counter" value is just to demonstrate that the render is being done twice. I actually dont need that variable